# Strikethrough text in Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.entry

Recently I have come across a business need where I have to show strikethrough text in the Entry of Xamarin Forms. Now there is a Text decoration property for strikethrough in Label, But there is no such property that exists for Entry.
Now we have an entry like this,
[image]

But we need to show a strikethrough over **sddad**. There are some resources that say to use effects or Unicode’s strikethrough character set. But it does not fulfill our needs.
Does anybody know how to implement this so that we can change the text to have a strikethrough via a property binding?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, android doesn't support strikethrough on their text entry. So Xamarin Forms does not attempt to support that. If you google `android strike through text entry`, you can find android (java) code, to make your own "custom control". You could make a Xamarin `Custom Renderer`, and hand-translate that java code to C#. The alternative is to "cheat": Make a one-cell grid. In that grid, lay a "label with strikethrough" on top of your Entry. So it "looks like" it is inside the Entry. Then its a question of how you make that dynamic as user types. Look into `Effects` and `Triggers`.

Comment: I am not sure what does the property binding for the Entry. Do you want to make the strikethrough for the update input one by one? Or you just want to change it when you input all the chanracters like converter to change the value?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT we want to show the strikethrough depending on a flag, like Ischecked property in checkbox. And we want that property to be bindable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you want custom UI behaviour in Xamarin.Forms that is not exposed through the Forms API, you will need to go down to the platform level.

The strikethrough text can be achieved using any of: `CustomRenderer`, `Effect`, `Behaviour`.

Below is an example of a platform effect that will strikethrough the whole text:

### Define An Effect

In your cross platform project create a new `RoutingEffect`:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StrikethroughEntry.Effects
{
    public class StrikethroughEntryEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public StrikethroughEntryEffect()
            : base("StrikethroughEntry.Effects.StrikethroughEntryEffect")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### Implement On iOS

Somewhere in your iOS project create a `PlatformEffect`

```cs
using Foundation;
using StrikethroughEntry.Effects;
using StrikethroughEntry.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("StrikethroughEntry.Effects")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(iOSStrikethroughEntryEffect), nameof(StrikethroughEntryEffect))]

namespace StrikethroughEntry.iOS
{
    public class iOSStrikethroughEntryEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private static NSNumber _strikethroughStyle => new NSNumber((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single);

        private string _originalText;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var textField = Control as UITextField;

            if (textField is null)
                return;

            _originalText = textField.Text;

            var attributedText = new NSMutableAttributedString(textField.Text);

            attributedText.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle, _strikethroughStyle, new NSRange(0, textField.Text.Length));

            textField.AttributedText = attributedText;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            var textField = Control as UITextField;

            if (textField is null)
                return;

            textField.AttributedText = null;

            textField.Text = _originalText;
        }
    }
}
```

This sample shows how you can cleanup the effect once it is no longer needed. The way attributed strings works on iOS would make is very easy to extend your strikethrough behaviour to target parts of the entry. Perhaps you only want to strikethrough specific words etc.

### Implement On Android

Somewhere in your Android project create a `PlatformEffect`:

```cs
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Widget;
using StrikethroughEntry.Droid;
using StrikethroughEntry.Effects;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("StrikethroughEntry.Effects")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(AndroidStrikethroughEntryEffect), nameof(StrikethroughEntryEffect))]

namespace StrikethroughEntry.Droid
{
    public class AndroidStrikethroughEntryEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        private PaintFlags _originalFlags;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            var editText = Control as EditText;

            if (editText is null)
                return;

            _originalFlags = editText.PaintFlags;

            editText.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.StrikeThruText;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            var editText = Control as EditText;

            if (editText is null)
                return;

            editText.PaintFlags = _originalFlags;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation would require updating if you wanted to strikethrough specific areas of your `Entry`.

### Consume The Effect

This example will be through xaml:

- Import the effects namespace: `xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:StrikethroughEntry.Effects"`
- Add effect to target `Entry`:

```xml
<Entry Text="This entry has strikethrough">
    <Entry.Effects>
        <effects:StrikethroughEntryEffect />
    </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

### Results

Now you have a lovely `Entry` with strikethrough text!

| Android | iOS |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Android Entry With Strikethrough] | [image: iOS Entry With Strikethrough] |

Comment: As this is a great solution, but can you give me some idea about how to make the strikethrough a bindable property?

Comment: If you want to create it as a bindable property, you can add those to the effect. I suggest looking at how the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Effects/IconTintColor) implements bindable properties on effects. You could either do a bool for true/false, a string for which words you want to strikethrough. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the guidence.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a custom renderer, using the code from the effects as I have shown you and add a new property to the control on the forms end. This might be a bit simpler in this case!